# Cannot import JS file in Vite

Tags: javascript, vite

I never use Vite and I'm starting to using it in a new Rails app.

I'm trying to use a bootstrap based admin theme in my app and I'm using Vite for JS.

I have an entrypoint with this line

```
import '../admin/vendor/metronic/components/_init'
```

Inside the _init.js file I have the inizialization of the js components of the theme

```js
var KTComponents = function () {
  // Public methods
  return {
      init: function () {
          KTApp.init();
          KTDrawer.init();
          KTMenu.init();
          KTScroll.init();
          KTSticky.init();
          KTSwapper.init();
          KTToggle.init();
          KTScrolltop.init();
          KTDialer.init();
          KTImageInput.init();
          KTPasswordMeter.init();
      }
  }
}();

// On document ready
if (document.readyState === "loading") {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    KTComponents.init();
  });
} else {
  KTComponents.init();
}

// Init page loader
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  KTApp.initPageLoader();
});

// Declare KTApp for Webpack support
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
  window.KTComponents = module.exports = KTComponents;
}
```

Of course I have this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: KTApp is not defined
```

To solve the issue I try to add

```
import KTApp from './app';
```

But I have this error now

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/vite-dev/admin/vendor/metronic/components/app.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at _init.js?t=1668157592237:6:8)
```

This is the app.js file

```js
"use strict";

// Class definition
var KTApp = function () {
  ...
}
    
// Declare KTApp for Webpack support
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = KTApp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't export KTApp in the app.js file with declartion. That's why the error is saying " does not provide an export named 'default' ". Try this `export default  KTApp = function(){}`.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: KTApp is not defined
    at null:4:22
(anonymous) @ null:4

Comment: Try wrapping KTApp with curly braces in import statement. import {KTApp} from './app';